# Can I forward the request from Kong server to my own servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, kong

I added my api to Kong like

```
curl -i -X POST \
 --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
 --data 'name=nirmal2' \
 --data 'target_url=http://localhost:8080/switch/apikongcall.do' \
 --data 'public_dns=mockbin10.com'
```

targer url is my servlet running on apache tomcat

When I am trying to verify whether kong is hitting my servlet like

```
curl -i -X GET \
 --url http://localhost:9023/ \
 --header 'Host: mockbin10.com'
```

It can not recognize the resource.
Should'nt it hit my servlet?

Answer (score 0):

In your last command, are you sure the Kong API port is running on `9023` ?

By default it runs on `8000`:

Try with:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 --url http://localhost:8000/ \
 --header 'Host: mockbin10.com'
```